# Interface method with multiple return types

Tags: object, go, interface

I'm struggling with interfaces. Consider this:

```
type Generatorer interface {
    getValue() // which type should I put here ? 
}

type StringGenerator struct {
    length         int
}

type IntGenerator struct {
    min            int
    max            int
}

func (g StringGenerator) getValue() string {
    return "randomString"
}

func (g IntGenerator) getValue() int {
    return 1
}
```

I want the `getValue()` function to return a **`string`** or an **`int`**, depending on if it's called from `StringGenerator` or `IntGenerator`

When I try to compile this, I get following error:

> cannot use s (type *StringGenerator) as type Generatorer in array or
>   slice literal: 
>     *StringGenerator does not implement Generatorer (wrong type for getValue method)
>
> have getValue() string
>     want getValue()

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How would you do the same in Java? What use is an interface that can return different stuff depending on its implementation? That doesn't sound like the right job for an interface to me (neither in Go nor in Java).

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele I have submitted my code on stackreview here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/168955/generate-thousands-of-json-documents-in-go. The question explains the goal of the project and why I need interface to solve my problem!

Comment: Ah, everything is dynamic, that explains! Go's main strength is in staticly typed problems, so I would say this problem is not the best match for the language. Of course it's possible and just as in Java [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) is most likely the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could* achieve it in this way:

```
type Generatorer interface {
    getValue() interface{}
}

type StringGenerator struct {
    length         int
}

type IntGenerator struct {
    min            int
    max            int
}

func (g StringGenerator) getValue() interface{} {
    return "randomString"
}

func (g IntGenerator) getValue() interface{} {
    return 1
}
```

The empty interface allows every value. This allows for generic code but basically stops you from using the very powerful type system of Go.

In your example if you use the `getValue` function, you will get a variable of type `interface{}` and if you want to work with it, you need to know if it actually is a string or an int: you will need a lot of `reflect` making your code slow.

Coming from Python I was used to code very generic. When learning Go I had to stop thinking that way.

What that means in your specific case I can't say because I don't know what `StringGenerator` and `IntGenerator` are being used for.

Comment: I am in a similar situation, albeit slightly different. In my case getValue would return a (different) struct, but these two different structs return at the end the very same struct. So it's pretty deterministic but it seems I can't do that easily either.

Comment: What do those structs do? What do they have in common that you want them to be returned from the same function? If you can answer that, create an interface with exactly those functions they have in common and implement those functions on both structs. Then `getValue` can return that interface (not the empty interface) and you don't need reflection.

Comment: Ok so here the background. These two structs are slightly different, we are in financial, one is about a trade struct, the other about a transfer struct, the goal is to calculate the quantity at the end. Also the trade struct shall implement some specific function not common to the transfer struct and the other way around. Anyway at the end they return a quantity. So this concept of interface is good, but I can't come to do something like that `qty(trade{}).calculateForX().get()` where qty() and get() can be called from both struct, but calculateForX() is a method only for trade struct...

Comment: So my case is exactly like the OP where each struct shall return a different type at the end, it's just the a more advanced use case. My current workaround is to do it without interface simply like that `qtyGetForTrade(trade{}).calculateForX().get()`, and have another function for transfer, it's just less beautiful...

Comment: @ChristopheVidal: can you create a new question here so I can properly answer? That is easier since I would like to make a code proposal. Best link the question here.

Comment: sure. Here is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637078/go-interface-method-with-multiple-return-types

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this the way you want to. You can, however, declare the function as

```
type Generatorer interface {
    getValue() interface{}
}
```

if you want it to return different types in different implementations.