# How to create an interface method with multiple return types

Tags: go, interface

This is a follow up to this question: [Interface method with multiple return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055953/interface-method-with-multiple-return-types/45057403?noredirect=1#comment107273413_45057403)

I have two structs which are slightly different. One is about a trade struct, the other about a transfer struct. The goal is to calculate the quantity at the end. Also the trade struct shall implement some specific function not common to the transfer struct and the other way around. At the end they all call a `get()` function and ultimately return the quantity (type string). I can't come to do something like that `qtyGetService(trade{}).calculateA().get()` where `qtyGetService()` and `get()` can be called from both struct, but `calculateA()` is a method only for trade struct. Interfaces look at first promising to solve such issues but I'm facing the issue described in that question [Interface method with multiple return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055953/interface-method-with-multiple-return-types/45057403) that a method in an interface must return a specific type. Returning an `interface{}` wouldn't be an option either as I would not be able to chain the functions like shown in the example below (not even mentioning the use of `reflect`).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Trade struct {
    q   string
    // many other attributes
}

type Transfer struct {
    q   string
    // many other attributes
}

type TradeService struct {
    q       string
    // some other attributes
}

type TransferService struct {
    q       string
    // some other attributes
}

type GetQty struct {
    q       string
    // some other attributes
}

func qtyGetTradeService(str *Trade) *TradeService {
    // some processing on the initial struct
    return &TradeService{
        q: str.q + " TradeService ",
    }
}

func qtyGetTransferService(str *Transfer) *TransferService {
    // some processing on the initial struct
    return &TransferService{
        q: str.q + " TransferService ",
    }
}

func (ts *TradeService) calculateA() *GetQty {
    // some processing on ts
    return &GetQty{
        q: ts.q + " CalculateA ",
    }
}

func (ts *TradeService) calculateB() *GetQty {
    // some processing on ts
    return &GetQty{
        q: ts.q + " CalculateB ",
    }
}

func (ts *TransferService) calculateC() *GetQty {
    // some processing on ts
    return &GetQty{
        q: ts.q + " CalculateC ",
    }
}

func (gq *GetQty) get() string{
    // some processing on gq common to both trade and transfer
    return gq.q + " CommonGet "
}



func main() {
    // this works just fine
    fmt.Println(qtyGetTradeService(&Trade{q: "10"}).calculateA().get())
    fmt.Println(qtyGetTransferService(&Transfer{q: "10"}).calculateC().get())

    // But this would be "better" to do something like this:
    fmt.Println(qtyGetService(&Trade{q: "10"}).calculateA().get())
    fmt.Println(qtyGetService(&Transfer{q: "10"}).calculateC().get())
}
```

Link to playground: https://play.golang.org/p/SBCs_O9SL0k

Comment: Use interfaces. Define a shared method on all the types with the same signature, then define an interface declaring the same method. Then you can call it regardless of the underlying type.

Comment: Stop programming Java in Go.

Comment: Please excuse if you misunderstood my comment. You really have to stop trying to write Java code in Go as this is simply not possible. E.g. you write "some processing on gq common to both trade and transfer" in the get method. In Go you use _functions_ to do common work, not methods. In Java you _have_ to put everything into a method and you can in your case because you have inheritance. There is no inheritance in Go but there are functions and you put common computations into functions. In Go you use methods to A) satisfy interfaces and B) for information hiding.

Comment: Most likely you can get rid of all these Services and replace them (or other parts by simple functions, possibly operating on interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

Thx for reposting the question. In the comments of the other question it would have been hard to provide a code example.

I see 2 options you have here:

## Option 1:

Create a function `calculate` on all structs with the same signature. In your example there are no input params, only a return value. If that is not the case, things get a bit more complex and option 2 might be a better fit.

Note: chaining functions makes it harder to use interfaces in Go. You might want to get rid of that.

Example:

```golang
type qty interface{
    calculate() qty // chaining can be problematic. best no return value here.
    get() string // or whatever type get should return
}

func (ts *TradeService) calculate() qty {
    ts.calculateA()
    return ts
}

func (ts *TransferService) calculate() qty {
    ts.calculateC()
    return ts
}

func main() {
    // Now this should 
    fmt.Println(qtyGetService(&Trade{q: "10"}).calculate().get())
    fmt.Println(qtyGetTransferService(&Transfer{q: "10"}).calculate().get())

    // or without chaining (if the return value is removed from `calculate`):
    printVal(qtyGetService(&Trade{q: "10"}))
    printVal(qtyGetTransferService(&Transfer{q: "10"}))
}

func printVal(service qty) {
    service.calculate()
    fmt.Println(service.get())
}
```

Sometimes it makes sense to implement a function on a struct even if it is not needed to satisfy an interface. If there is a service that doesn't need to calculate before calling `get` just create this function:

```golang
func (ts *SomeService) calculate() {}
```

Now it can be used as `qty` interface.

## Option 2:

It could also be that the cases are not so uniform and harder to bring into a single interface.

Then you could work with multiple interfaces and cast the struct to check if it implements the interface. Only then call the method. This is more or less like a check if the struct has a certain method or not.

```golang
type calculatorA interface {
    calculateA()
}

type calculatorB interface {
    calculateB()
}

type getter interface {
    get()
}

func main() {
    service := qtyGetService(&Trade{q: "10"})
    if ok, s := service.(calculatorA); ok {
        s.calculateA()
    }
    if ok, s := service.(calculatorB); ok {
        s.calculateB()
    }
    var val string
    if ok, s := service.(getter); ok {
        val = s.get()
    }
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

Hope this is applicable to your case and gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you. I think that option 2 shall (technically) work, but it wouldn't really make sense in a practical way as it's not simplifying much anything. As for Option 1 I'm not sure to understand how this would be possible. What I would like to do is to replace `qtyGetTransferService` and `qtyGetTradeService` by 2 `qtyGetService` function based off Trade and Transfer struct. Then each of this function would return a *different* struct which in turn is implemented by a number of `calculateXX()` - note that in my example I have `calculateA` and `calculateB` for Trade, `calculateC` for Transfer.

Comment: If they are so different, then there is no good way to do this. This is actually where many people have a problem in the beginning (not sure if you are new to Go or not): A different thinking is required for Go which can only be learned with time. My advice: don't try to optimise the code structure too early. Just have multiple copies of things that look similar. It's ok. In the long run it will even be more maintainable. I now have 4 years of Go experience and I still have to live with some coding decisions I made with 1.5 years of experience. I will have to refactor them some day.

Comment: Most of those decisions have to do with over-engineering: 1) writing code to be more flexible than it has to be right now. 2) writing code that is capable of handling multiple cases that could have been separated; now there are too many if statements in there making the code hard to read and hard to maintain. multiple copies of it would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `GetService()` receptor to both `Trade` and `Transfer` like this:

```
func (t Trade) GetService() *TradeService {
    return &TradeService{
        q: t.q + " TradeService ",
    }
}

func (t Transfer) GetService() *TransferService {
    return &TransferService{
        q: t.q + " TransferService ",
    }
}
```

You will be able to use it like this:

```
    fmt.Println(Trade{q: "10"}.GetService().calculateA().get())
    fmt.Println(Transfer{q: "10"}.GetService().calculateC().get())
```

Seems to be what you are trying to accomplish.

Defining `GetService()` in a interface would not work because the return type of both implementations is different.